# $i \equiv k \mod p \implies i = k$ if $p$ is prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

In a particular proof of Fermat's Little Theorem $\big(a^{p} \equiv a \mod p \big)$ in Engel, the following fact is used $i \equiv k \mod p \implies i = k \:$ where $p$ is a prime. I'm not really sure why this true because we can always have $i = qp + k$ with $i > p > k$

**UPDATE:**

The previous part of the proof assumes $(a , p) = 1$ and then considers the sequence $a, 2a, 3a, ... (p-1)a$ so $i,k \in 1,2,...p-1$
$$ia \equiv ka \mod p \implies i \equiv k \mod p $$
 so if $i = qp+k \implies i >p$. And this is a contradiction. Perhaps this is why the fact is true in this case?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the text, but if what Engel writes is true, he may have bounded the set which includes $i$ and $k$. Another possibility is that $i$ and $k$ belong to a set of p numbers which are distinct $\mod(p)$.

Comment: @ChrisSanders That seems to be the case, occured to me as I was writing my question. Although I'm not too confident in my insight to be sure of what I think.

Comment: The question must be missing some context...please edit it to include more necessary details as $29\equiv2\pmod3$ contradicts the statement..